# Are there random variables $X,Y$ such that $X,Y,X+Y \sim N(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let's suppose we have two, not necessarily independent, random variables $X,Y \sim N(0,1)$.

Then, is it possible that $X+Y \sim N(0,1)$?

What I have managed to show is that because $Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2Cov(X,Y)$ it would be necessary that $Cov(X,Y) = -1/2$.

But I'm still looking for an example or else a proof that it is not possible.

Comment: Are you familiar with the multivariate normal distribution? Like if $(X, Y) \sim N(0, \Sigma)$ then $X + Y \sim N(0, \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2 + 2\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y))$? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Correlated_random_variables

Comment: For an explicit example, take $X$ and $V$ independent $N(0,1)$,  $Y = -X/2 + \sqrt{3} V/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. Suppose
$$(X,Y)'\sim\mathcal{N}\bigg(\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&-\frac{1}{2}\\-\frac{1}{2}&1\end{pmatrix}\bigg)$$

And consider the vector $(1,1)$. Then $(1,1)\cdot (X,Y)'=X+Y$ is distributed Normal with mean

$$(1,1)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}=0$$

and variance

$$(1,1)\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1&-\frac{1}{2}\\-\frac{1}{2}&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}=1$$

Which is what you want.

**Note:** By a similar argument, using the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ you have that $X$ and $Y$ are standard normals on their own.

**Note:** One should be careful and make sure that the variance-covariance matrix is a valid one. One way of doing it is by directly checking it is possitive semi-definite, which is true in this case as the first principal minor is $1$ and the determinant is $5/4$, both strictly positive.

There is an easy second way to verify that a $2$ by $2$ matrix is a valid variance-covariance matrix. Call this matrix $\Sigma$. If you can verify that the diagonal entries are strictly positive, the matrix is symmetric and that there exists $\rho\in[-1,1]$, a valid correlation coefficient, such that $\Sigma_{21}=\Sigma_{12}=\rho\cdot(\Sigma_{11}\cdot\Sigma_{22})^{1/2}$, you are done. In this case $\rho=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Nice example

Comment: The answer is incomplete. You still need to show that the matrix is positive definite in order to be a valid covariance matrix.

Comment: @shalop you are right. I thought in this case it was straightforward, but I'll add an additional note.

Answer (score -1):

The pdf of the sum of two absolutely continuous random variables is simply given by the convolution of the pdf's of the variables. In our case, $f_X(x) = f_Y(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$, so $f_{X + Y}(x) = \int_{- \infty}^\infty f_X(t)f_Y(x - t) dt = \frac{1}{4} \int_{- \infty}^\infty \exp(- \frac{t^2 + (x - t)^2}{2}) dt = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{- \infty}^\infty \exp(- \frac{(t \sqrt{2})^2 - 2 t \sqrt{2} \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{ x^2}{2}}{2}) dt = \frac{1}{2 \pi} e^{-\frac{ x^2}{4}} \int_{- \infty}^\infty \exp(- \frac{(t \sqrt{2} - \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})^2}{2}) dt = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2} \pi} e^{- \frac{x^2}{4}} \int_{- \infty}^\infty e^{- \frac{u^2}{2}} du = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2} \pi} e^{- \frac{x^2}{4}} \sqrt{2 \pi} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} e^{- \frac{x^2}{4}}.$ In particular, the sum of two normals of mean $0$ and variance $1$ is not a normal of mean $0$ and variance $1$. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: This is only true if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Ah, I misread that they are independent.